# Rails 4 multiple form (User and Address)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with creating multiple form for User and Address models. When I load page, I don't see address fields.

Me source code is below

models/address

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

models/user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

controllers/users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_address
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :first_name, 
    :last_name, 
    :email, 
    :password, 
    :password_confirmation,
    addresses_attributes: [:id, :city]
  )
end
end
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  ...
  <% form.fields_for :address do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= builder.label :city %><br />
      <%= builder.text_field :city %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit "Register" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small typo by excluding the `=` in the ERB tag for the `fields_for` call. It should be

```
<%= form.fields_for :address do |builder| %>
```

Without the `=` you won't actually be rendering the form.